# C# FormCollection to Dapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dapper

Is it possible to pass a FormCollection to Dapper? Will Dapper implement support for a FormCollection as a parameter?

```
public IActionResult MyForm(FormCollection form)
{
       dapper.Query("INSERT INTO.....", form);
}
```

Comment: You could wite an extension method on the FormCollection class which transforms FormCollection key-values to dynamic parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly pass a FormCollection to Dapper. You have to break out the values from the FormCollection into a type that Dapper accepts.

You should investigate using one of the following:

- [Dynamic Parameters](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Readme.md) (see section on stored procedures).
- [Dapper.Contrib Extensions](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib).
- [Table Valued Parameter (TVP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835519/Passing-Table-Valued-Parameters-with-Dapper

Answer (score 0):

Yes break out values to dynamicparameters is working, however I would like to request such a simple feature that dapper accepts a formcollection.

Comment: This isn't the place to ask for a feature request. You can do it on dapper's github site. https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net